# Snowflake external function throws "with remote service error: 400" when calling AWS lambda through API gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Am trying to call AWS lambda function through Snowflake external function via API gateway.
I had followed the snowflake documentation steps and everything works fine(I can retrieve results in snowflake) when I had used the examples which is there in the document.

But upon modifying the lambda code for as per the flow (Trying to replicate
https://medium.com/snowflake/governed-access-to-files-and-data-sharing-using-snowflake-unstructured-data-management-193b6fcda65e
), i could succesfully execute via lambda function only and not through snowflake external function.
It returns:

```
Request failed for external function GET_PDF_INFO with remote service error: 400"
```

When calling through AWS lambda function test code,am passing below JSON payload to test,which successfully returns

```
{
  "body":
    "{ \"data\": [ [ 0, \"<pre signed url>", \"page\" ], [ 1, \"<pre signed url>", \"life, the universe, and everything\" ] ] }"
}
```

But when called from snowflake i believe the JSON payload looks different as we see from the error:

```
Request failed for external function GET_PDF_INFO with remote service error: 400 '{ "data":[ [0,<pre signed url>","pdf"] ] }'; requests batch-id: 01a005a8-0000-1a86-0002-0d2e00016abe:2:0; request batch size: 1 rows; request retries: 0; response time (last retry): 1.67186s
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Apologize my bad!! Issue due to wrong s3 file name been passed to the payload.After correcting it,i could retrieve the output from AWS lambda to Snowflake.